# Is there a way to pass URL template tag from database to template in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

I apologize if my question is poorly worded. Basically, I am making a database of fictional characters and in the database, I have a biography of the character. I would like to link to other characters using the `{% url 'viewname' otherchar.slug %}` method. However, all I get back from the database is literally that line of code.

I understand it may not be possible, but is there a way to get Django to see that line and turn it into an absolute URL like it would if I manually added the URL tag into the page?

Something to add - I am using TinyMCE so the content in the database is being saved with HTML - I want to be able to save external links, subheadings, and whatnot, which is why I chose to use TinyMCE and its HTML field.

**models.py**

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    faction = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    rankIMG = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'rankIMG/', blank = True)
    department = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    content = HTMLField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

**views.py**

```
class CharacterFull(DetailView):
    model = Character
    context_object_name = 'character'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CharacterFull, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['factionDict'] = charFaction
        context['deptDict'] = charDepartment

        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'LCARS'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', LCARSView.LCARSHome.as_view(), name = 'lcarsHome'),
    path('Characters/', LCARSView.Characters.as_view(), name = 'characterHome'),
    path('Characters/p/<slug:slug>', LCARSView.CharacterPartialView, name = 'charPartialView'),
    path('Characters/<slug:slug>/', LCARSView.CharacterFull.as_view(), name = 'characterView'),
]
```

**template (relevant code)**

```
<div class="col-md-8 p-4 text-justify border border-secondary rounded shadow">
    {{ character.content|safe }}
</div>
```

**page source example (if it's helpful)**

```
<p dir="ltr">He was also assigned <a href="{% url 'LCARS:characterView' character.slug %}">Commander Shampoo</a> as his...
```

I appreciate any assistance you guys can be of. I can't seem to find anything on here or on Google. Thanks!

Comment: I made a slight edit to add my urls.py file in case that would help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the content in the `get_context_data` as a template:

```
from django.template import Template, RequestContext

class CharacterFull(DetailView):
    model = Character
    context_object_name = 'character'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['factionDict'] = charFaction
        context['deptDict'] = charDepartment
        self.object.other_attribute = Template(
            self.object.content
        ).render(RequestContext(self.request, context))
        return context
```

where `.other_attribute` is an identifier you do *not* use as a field, property, method, etc.

and then render this in the "outer" template with:

```
<div class="col-md-8 p-4 text-justify border border-secondary rounded shadow">
    {{ character.other_attribute|safe }}
</div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly you wonderful person. Thank you.

So that solution basically prerenders the 'content' field from the database so that the Jinga tags will be processed before actually rendering it into the template for display?